# Missing Classpath Entry for WSo2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to setup Integration Studio with Enterprise Integrator 6.5 and I'm getting a missing Classpath entry while adding a server.

Missing classpath entry C:\WSO2-updates\IntegrationStudio\wso2\lib

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a valid WSO2 Enterprise Integrator Server as the CARBON_HOME. After adding a server that error should resolve. You can download WSO2 EI from https://wso2.com/integration/

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue after adding the server from the 'Browse' button?